# Making one div visible at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make when some presses a button that only one div is visible at a time. So when they click another button, that corresponding div pops up and the last one hides.

I've tried a for loop:

```
function display(x) {

    for (i=0; i<content.length; i++){
        content[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    if(x = content[i]){
        x.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

This didn't do anything.

I tried nesting the if statement inside the loop, but it caused all to be visible.

I've linked the jsfiddle below.

Please no jQuery answers as I'm trying to learn pure javascript first.

Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/ethacker/rp59g9cf/

Comment: That's because `i` will = to `content.length`, in your `for()` `i` will be +1 each time it's run so at the end of for your loop it will target the last array element of `content` Try placing your if condition inside of your for loop?

Comment: Also not sure why you target each `button[]` the way you are. Why not run them in a `for()` loop and use `i` to set the event call? Example `buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {display(content[i])};` since  the index of the button is equal to the index of `content[]` you want to pass...

Answer (score 1):

You are not putting the `if` inside the loop. Therefore, it will only check the last value of `i`. Also, the equals should be `==`. You should do it like this:

```
function display(x) {

    for (i=0; i<content.length; i++){
        if(x == content[i]){
            x.style.display = 'inline';
        } else {
            content[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Part of the reason it isn't working is that he has `if(x = content[i])`, which doesn't work here. Should be `if(x === content[i])`. EDIT: Just saw you already did that!

Comment: I just noticed, you can ignore my proposed change. :)

Comment: @SHBelsky  also the OP has the if condition outside of the for loop :p

Answer (score 0):

see this [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ujrn27tv/) code I slightly modified your code

```
var currDisplayElm;
//function
function display(content) {

    if(currDisplayElm)
       currDisplayElm.style.display = 'none';

    currDisplayElm = content;
    content.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand.
Ithink If you call function on click of button then set div Id in sequence and you should pass thet div no which you want to display. 
And div name must be same then you can hide other div.
I hope you understand ..